# First try - graphical program

Tags: c++, opengl

I used a book called **Computer Graphices using OpenGL**.

*at page number 51 i found this code*

```
#include <windows.h>
#include "glut.h" 

//<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< method(s) >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
void My_Display(void); 
void My_Inti(void); 

//<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< main method >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv); 
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB); 
    glutInitWindowSize(640, 480); 
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 150); 
    glutCreateWindow("my second try "); 
    glutDisplayFunc(My_Display);

    My_Inti(); 
    glutMainLoop(); 



    return 0;
}

//<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< IMPLEMENTING METHOD(S) >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>.

//<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< My_Inti >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
void My_Inti(void)
{
    glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 0); // white color 
    glColor3f(0, 0, 0); // Black color 
    glPointSize(10); // point size is 10 pixel this is big .
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);  
    glLoadIdentity(); 
    gluOrtho2D(0, 640, 0, 480); 
}


//<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< My_Display >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
void My_Display(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); 
    glBegin(GL_POINT);
    glVertex2i(100, 50);
    glVertex2i(100, 130);
    glVertex2i(150, 130); 
    glEnd();
    glFlush();
}
```

all what i add to this code is the comments and i change a little at the variable ; nothing more .

When we come to the problem this code work fine but it didn't creat the three points at the display method ?

Comment: note sorry the include code was a bit more but i included glut.h already so i don't need to include everything which are all in glut.h and i already included them all and the same result ...

Comment: i change the code after and take the point size and color before the point and it work but i had to write it for every point ..

Comment: Can you try changing the `GLUT_SINGLE` in the init code to `GLUT_DOUBLE`, and replace the `glFlush()` at the end of `My_Display()` with `glutSwapBuffers()`? The example is using single buffered rendering, which I guess should still work on most platforms, but it's very uncommon these days.

Comment: i did so didn't work .. the same white page ..

Comment: Also, if you're just starting out, you may want to be aware that almost everything this code shows are deprecated features in current OpenGL versions.

Comment: what do you suggest me to do , sir ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is just one missing letter. Instead of this:

```
glBegin(GL_POINT);
```

The correct value is:

```
glBegin(GL_POINTS);
```

The first thing I would do any time you get no rendering, or not the expected rendering, is to call `glGetError()`, and see if it returns an error. I admit that I didn't see this problem initially, but calling `glGetError()` would have pointed it out quickly.

BTW: In case anybody else is surprised that there are both `GL_POINT` and `GL_POINTS` enums in OpenGL. `GL_POINT` is one of the possible arguments to `glPolygonMode()`, as opposed to `GL_POINTS` which denotes one of the possible primitive types for draw calls.

Comment: Excellent -- I got that far but could not figure out how `GL_POINT` was considered valid as well!

Comment: Yeah, I searched for it in gl.h to figure out what it was once I realized that `GL_POINT` existed as well.

Comment: Thank you very much .
more than what i want .
glGetError() is a great function thnx for telling me about it :)

Answer (score 1):

It does not work because there is an error in the source code (unlikely) or you mis-copied the argument for `glBegin(GL_POINT);` (likely).

Using

```
glBegin(GL_POINTS);
```

I got this image:

[image]