# Can't draw a Line and a point with c# Tao.OpengGL

Tags: c#, opengl

Using Tao.Freeglut and Tao.OpenGl.
I tried to create some points by typing this code.

But when I run it, it show only a white windows but didn't have any points on it.
Did someone know how to fix this problem.( same problem when i try to use GL_LINES with 2 points)

```
using Tao.Freeglut;
using Tao.OpenGl;

 public static void init()
        Gl.glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        Gl.glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        Gl.glPointSize(4);
        Gl.glMatrixMode(Gl.GL_PROJECTION);
        Gl.glLoadIdentity();
        Glu.gluOrtho2D(0.0, 400, 0.0, 300.0);

    }

    public static void myDisplay()
    {

        Gl.glClear(Gl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        Gl.glBegin(Gl.GL_POINT);
        {
            Gl.glVertex2i(50, 50);
            Gl.glVertex2i(100, 100);
            Gl.glVertex2i(100, 150);
            Gl.glVertex2i(200, 200);
            Gl.glVertex2i(200, 250);
            Gl.glEnd();
        }
        Gl.glFlush();
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        Glut.glutInit();
        Glut.glutInitDisplayMode(Glut.GLUT_SINGLE | Glut.GLUT_RGB);
        Glut.glutInitWindowPosition(50, 100);
        Glut.glutInitWindowSize(400, 300);
        Glut.glutCreateWindow("Test 2");

        init();
        Glut.glutDisplayFunc(myDisplay);
        Glut.glutMainLoop();
    }
```

Comment: Please edit your question title to be more descriptive than "Help!" and repeating the tags.

Comment: [Learn to write good title](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). To be honest, I've not read your question yet. Better title brings better answers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [First try - graphical program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23597472/first-try-graphical-program)

Comment: Sorry for the BAD title. this is my first time to write a topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Gl.glBegin(Gl.GL_POINT);
```

will cause a GL_INVALID_ENUM error, since GL_POINT is not a valid argument to glBegin. Check out [the documentation](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glBegin.xml) one which draw modes are valid. You should also check for OpenGL errors at least at the end of a frame.

Comment: You should probably mention that the correct enum is `GL_POINTS`.

Comment: You could also have mentioned that immediate mode (`glBegin` … `glEnd`) is deprecated.

Comment: Thank you. First, when I type GL_POI and it Pop this GL_POINT up

Comment: First, When I type GL_POI and it pop this up GL_POINT and I choose it.But when I checked the reference ,It must be GL_POINTS.

Thank You.